# R : Error when using "lines" instruction for a previously defined function in a loop

Tags: r, function, for-loop, lines

I have a problem when I use "lines" into a loop, which is used to plot the functions that I have defined into the loop. My purpose is to plot x³,x⁴,x⁵. I leave my code so that you can see which are the problems.

Thank you in advance.

```
x <- seq(0,1,0.05)
plot(x,x,type="l",ylab="y")
j <-3
for(j in 3:5){
  f1 <- function(a){
        a^j
        }
  lines(f1)

  j <- j+1
}
```

Comment: lines (f1(a)) doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly advise to plot using `ggplot2` regarding this kind of problem:

```
library(ggplot2)

df = data.frame(x=x, y=c(x^2,x^3,x^4), func=rep(paste0('x',2:4), each=length(x)))

ggplot(df,aes(x,y,color=func))+geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that you call `f1(a)` without specifying `a`. The second problem is that when you do not specify the x and y values for 'lines()', the x values are assumed to be `1:n`. Therefore, the line is plotted but not on the same interval. To see this you can run the following code.

```
x <- seq(0,1,0.05)
plot(x,x,type="l",ylab="y",xlim=c(0,length(x)+1))
j <-3

f1 <- function(a){
  a^j
}

for(j in 3:5){
  lines(f1(x))
}
```

Here is some code that will generate a simple plot with all lines on the same interval.

```
x <- seq(0,1,0.05)
plot(x,x,type="l",ylab="y")
j <-3

f1 <- function(a){
  a^j
}

for(j in 3:5){
  lines(x,f1(x))
}
```

[image]